# How do I address cases when a transaction completes in the database but a connectivity issue causes an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

In my Azure web service I have code that invokes a stored procedure in SQL Azure. Sometimes it happens so that the stored procedure completes but the connection is broken afterwards and the caller gets a `SqlException` claiming that `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

The caller will then reopen the connection and try to rerun the same code. The problem is that the code first checks that the database table stores "the right state" and since the abovementioned stored procedure has already been run the database state has changed and so the check is failed and an exception is thrown.

So the problem is the calling code relies on the condition that "no exceptions" equals "database change okay" and so if there was an exception then the database has not changed. In this case an exception is because of temporary connectivity problems after the database change has occurred so the assumption turns out to be wrong.

What's the typical way to address such cases?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to identify why the timeout SQL Exception occurs?

Comment: @Jamie Keeling: Nope, it's something network related. It's just there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DTC and remote transaction, then at least you are properly handling this. You must promote that from a "local" to a "distributed" transaction. This has issues in itself, but there is hardly another way to do it properly.

Alternatively you can reprogram so that you handle this situation in code properly.

Comment: Where do I start with going the "DTC" way? Where do I start with the "reprogram" way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [Enterprise Library Transient Fault Handling Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680901%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx). We have started incorporating it in our Web Roles.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve the problem entirely is to make the transactions [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), which is a fancy way of saying that no matter how many times you run the procedure the final state is the correct one. Once you do that then it doesn't matter if the first transaction (or the second, third, fourth, etc) failed. You just keep trying until it works, and then you know you've got the right state.

How exactly you achieve idempotence is situational. In many cases you can use guard clauses to check if you're already in the desired state, but other times you might need to do something more complex.